# android move image from one place to another place on different screen size and resolutions

Tags: android, resolution, screen-size

I am new in android. I want to make ludo game. and I sets all things related to this game. but I want to move TOKEN from one place to another for different screens like (Nexus 6, Samsung Note 5, Moto G3, etc...). But issue is that for every screen size (Width x Height) are different. that's why I am not set proper x and y position on screen. I referenced screen Height and Width for taking next position (x and y) on screen to move TOKEN on screen. I am taking static image for Ludo Dashboard. That's why i am not getting how to move.

for example:
My Screen is as below,

[image]

1. from origin position to Home position :
   In this situation, for every screens translation was changed. because i am taking reference screen Height and Width for move.
   for that code is below,

   ```
   DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
   getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
   this.constant.Height = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
   this.constant.Width = displaymetrics.widthPixels;

   private float getheight(float val) {
       return (this.constant.Height * val) / 800;
   }

   private float getwidth(float val) {
       return (this.constant.Width * val) / 480;
   }

   ObjectAnimator animTranslateY = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(img,
           "translationY", blue_1.getY() + getheight(67));
   animTranslateY.setDuration(GameConstants.DURATION);

   ObjectAnimator animTranslateX = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(img,
           "translationX", blue_1.getX() + getwidth(128));
   animTranslateX.setDuration(GameConstants.DURATION);

   AnimatorSet anim = new AnimatorSet();
   anim.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
       @Override
       public void onAnimationStart(Animator animator) {
       }

       @Override
       public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animator) {

       }

       @Override
       public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animator) {

       }

       @Override
       public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animator) {

       }
   });

   anim.play(animTranslateX);
   anim.play(animTranslateY);
   anim.start();
   ```
2. from Home to Common Rout : 
   In this situation, its work fine. bt for different screen its moving differ.

So, my question is that How can i move and what should be reference for move image form one position to another position. I takes too many time for this. Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I tried to come up with a solution that uses simple unitary method to solve your problem. I am not sure if it works, I did not try it by coding it actually!

I am assuming that you have set the background static image to scale its size (width) to 100% of the screen, your static image is a square(usually a ludo board is). Also I am considering here that screenwidth is smaller than screenheight. If it is the other way around then exchange the formulae symbols.

let

```
screenH = screen height in pixels;
screenW = screen width in pixels;

bgW = width of staticbackgroundimage in pixels;
bgH = height of staticbackgroundimage in pixels;
```

so now, if you want to move 'p' pixels in the background static ludo image horizontally then let us say you will have to move x pixels on the screen. x can be calculated as follows:

```
x= p*screenW/bgW;
```

Also, if you want to move 'q' pixels in the background static ludo image vertically then let us say you will have to move y pixels on the screen. y can be calculated as follows:

image height on the screen will be(in pixels):

```
screenHimage=bgH*screenW/bgW;

y=q*screenHimage/bgH;
```

So now move x and y pixels on the screen if you want to move p and q pixels in the original image.
I hope this works.

Comment: its worked... but in path, same issue having... because minor change will make big issue... help me if any else solution...